# Whenever object is created then execution goes to constructor or to instance variable?

Tags: java, constructor

I am new to java so when i was debugging a piece of code then i found out that the execution goes to constructor but before entering into the body of constructor it wen to the instance variable so can you please explain me the reason

```
   public class TestExecution 
    {
       int input1 = 5;
       int input2 = 6;

      TestExecution()
       {
        System.out.println(input1+"before main"+input2);
        int input1 = 10;
        int input2 = 11;
        System.out.println(input1+"after main"+input2);
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) 
       {
        TestExecution testExcution = new TestExecution();
        }
    }
```

Result was:

```
 5beforemain6   10aftermain11
```

Comment: you're hiding the instance variables with local variables

Comment: @UUID - is right. You are creating new local variables in the constructor. As far your original question goes, the question used to mark it as dup should help

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar:I just wanted to know why instance variable is executed before constructor variables.I just read the question for which i was duplicated but it dinot answer my question so if you could just help me in comment section then it will be helpful.

Comment: @DarkArmy - Did you check the second part of *meriton's* answer?

Comment: @DarkArmy - The fields are initialized before the actually statements of the constructor start executing..